# how to manually force commit @Transactional spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

```
serviceA.save(x);

syncToOtherServiceWithAPI(x.id);
```

```
// otherservice 
//fetchA(x.id) - but still haven't got the newest data because before not committed
```

how to get newest/updated data on other service?

Comment: Please show your code. There is too few information to help you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Technically no you cannot commit manually while using @Transactional, for this, you can check `TransactionTemplate` to do it programmatically.

If you are trying to commit transactionally inside your other transaction, then use `@Transactional (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`